# Transit Visa for Stockholm

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, layovers, transit-visas, sweden

I have a layover in Stockholm from the US on my way to the Czech Republic. I have both Czech and US passports. I need to pick up and recheck my bags. Will I need a transit visa?

Answer (score 4):

Under the freedom of movement directive, Czech citizens have a near-absolute right to enter Sweden and stay indefinitely, and US citizens can enter visa-free for up to 90 days after a successful landing interview.

So simply present your Czech passport and the Swedish police practically cannot question you wanting to enter.

In fact, even if you *didn't* need to pick up baggage, the Schengen Area (of which Sweden and Czech form a part) is a single country for border purposes, so you'd clear immigration in Stockholm only regardless, and not in Prague - flights Stockholm-Prague are effectively domestic